# How to always get rounded corners (corner-radius) on a view that has dynamic height?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm rather new to iOS programming.

I was wondering what is the proper way to achieve permanently rounded corners (via the attribute `view.layer.cornerRadius`) for a view that has dynamic height.

In Android, we would just set the `cornerRadius` to an absurdly high number like `1000`. This would result in the view always having rounded corners regardless of how tall or short it was.

Unfortunately, when I tried to do the same thing in iOS, I realized that an overly large value for `cornerRadius` results in the view being drawn in a distorted way - or straight up just disappearing from the layout altogether.

Anyone have any insights into this problem? Thanks.

Comment: set view.layer.cornerRadius = view.bounds.height/2 inside the viewDidLayoutSubview method

Comment: @RajaKishan Is there anyway to do this without having to modify `viewDidLayoutSubview(...)`? I ask because I want to avoid touching the inner-workings of outside dependencies as much as possible - while also achieving my desired result.

Comment: Use subclass of uiview and then use layout view method . You can also use main queue so no need to write this inside the layout method

Comment: @RajaKishan Could you elaborate on your answer in a post, please? As I already said, I am a beginner in Swift. I am not sure what you mean exactly by "use main queue". As for your suggestion of "Use subclass of uiview" - I am referring to views that are imported in from external dependencies (e.g. cocoapods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to achieve this with **RxSwift** by **observing Key Path**.

```
extension UIView{

    func cornerHalf(){
        clipsToBounds = true
        rx.observe(CGRect.self, #keyPath(UIView.bounds))
            .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
                self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width * 0.5
            }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Done in `init` method, the code seems simpler by declaration , instead of being distributed two parts. Especially, the logic is widely used in the  project.

Call like this:

```
 let update: UIButton = {
     let btn = UIButton()
     // more config
     btn.cornerHalf()
     return btn
 }()
```